# Can not render after redirect in node

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, pug

So, im trying to render after redirecting to a new directory in node

```
BusinessAddressDB.create({
    UserId : req.user.id,
    MainAddress : {
        Street : req.body.Street,
        City : req.body.City,
        ZipCode : req.body.ZipCode,
        State : req.body.State,
        Country : req.body.Country,

    }
}, function(err){
    //if(err) console.log('There is an error ' + err);
    return res.redirect('/Business/CreateBusinessCategories');
})
```

Then I do this

```
app.get('/Business/CreateBusinessCategories',function(req,res){
    console.log("inside create categories"); // it goes inside here but it does not render
    res.render('test.jade');  
})
```

And the test.jade inside the views

```
doctype html
html(lang='en')
   head
   body
       h2 Test Page
```

It does not give any error saying that it did not find `test.jade`....so it finds it. But not sure what it cant render `test.jade`
Any help please?

Comment: Have you configure views directory in express configuration

Comment: yes I have configured my views. When I remove test.jade....I get an error message saying that it can not find test.jade.

Comment: can you please show it?

Comment: This is my test.jade file.   for the app config it already goes to views when I run the app so it routes to the right directory. And redirecting is working fine in other pages. But not in here.   I did this in my app.js app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');

Comment: did you try by removing extension `.jade`?

Comment: Are you calling the original handler (the one that's doing the redirect) using AJAX?

Comment: yes I'm using ajax to make the call to the server side. Then I have my redirect to redirect to a new directory. Then I call my render method.